# How to compile C/C++ code into a .hex file for the BBC micro:bit?

Tags: bbc-microbit

I tried setting up the toolchain on Ubuntu 22.04 host to run the examples from https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-samples/ but I'm just unable to setup Yotta, I keep getting different dependency issues. What are the exact steps needed?

Answer (score 2):

After trying to setup the toolchain for a while, I finally decided to Google for a Docker image with the toolchain, and found https://github.com/carlosperate/docker-microbit-toolchain [at this commit](https://github.com/carlosperate/docker-microbit-toolchain/blob/ad2e52620d47f98c225647855432a854f65d9140/requirements.txt) from Carlos Atencio, a Micro:Bit foundation employee, and that just absolutely worked:

```
# Get the Docker image.
docker pull ghcr.io/carlosperate/microbit-toolchain:latest

# Get examples.
git clone https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-samples
cd microbit-samples
git checkout 285f9acfb54fce2381339164b6fe5c1a7ebd39d5

# Select a sample. It builds one at a time. The default one is the hello world.
cp source/examples/hello-world/* source

# Build and flash.
docker run -v $(pwd):/home --rm ghcr.io/carlosperate/microbit-toolchain:latest yotta build

# Flash.
cp build/bbc-microbit-classic-gcc/source/microbit-samples-combined.hex "/media/$USER/MICROBIT/"
```

And you can then flash the example you want to run with:

```
cp build/counter.hex "/media/$USER/MICROBIT/"
```

The source code for the hello world from https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-samples/blob/285f9acfb54fce2381339164b6fe5c1a7ebd39d5/source/examples/hello-world/main.cpp is:

```
#include "MicroBit.h"

MicroBit uBit;

int main()
{
    uBit.init();
    uBit.display.scroll("HELLO WORLD! :)");
    release_fiber();
}
```

Atencios' Docker setup explains how get yotta working if you still want that: https://github.com/carlosperate/docker-microbit-toolchain/blob/master/Dockerfile , the key is likely using his magically crafted `requirements.txt`, likely kept back from the day when things really worked, to avoid the infinitely many dependency issues of yotta. He's on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you've found a work around to compile C for the micro:bit. To answer your original question, here's what worked for me to install yotta on Debian 11.5. I have Python v3.9.2 installed.

```
sudo aptitude install python-setuptools cmake build-essential ninja-build python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev

pip3 install yotta --user
```